# Is changing elements with a mask during training valid in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, linear-regression

I have a forward function which contains a linear regression task that looks like this

```
class lin_reg(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,pre_trained_f):
        super(lin_reg, self).__init__()
        self.bbox_model = nn.Linear(4, 4,bias=True)
        self.bbox_model.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.eye(4))
        self.bbox_model.weight.requires_grad = False
        self.bbox_model.bias.requires_grad = True

    def forward(self, x, data,indicator_arr):
        x_hat = self.bbox_model(data)
        x[indicator_arr == False] = x_hat #Here is the questionable part
        ...
        ...
        "different operations which include the variable x only"
        ...
```

The `forward` function returns a value which depends on `x` and is used in the loss function. `indicator_arr` is an array which contains `True` or `False` values. The purpose is to mask specific parts of the matrix `x` and change them with ``` x``<sub>hat</sub> ``` for further process. `self.bbox_model` is a linear layer where only the bias vector is trained.

The problem that occurs is that the gradient of the bias vector is very low in fact near zero, therefore no training progress is made and my validation loss is high. Is the masking a possible reason for this or could any other error occur from this masking step during training?

I expect that the backpropagation function can backtrack everything correctly and the optimizer update the bias vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
class lin_reg(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,pre_trained_f):
        super(lin_reg, self).__init__()
        self.bbox_model = nn.Linear(4, 4,bias=True)
        self.bbox_model.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.eye(4))
        self.bbox_model.weight.requires_grad = False
        self.bbox_model.bias.requires_grad = True

    def forward(self, x, data,indicator_arr):
        mask = torch.tensor(indicator_arr, dtype=torch.float32, device=x.device)
        x_hat = self.bbox_model(data)
        masked_x_hat = mask * x_hat
        masked_x = mask * x
        masked_x += masked_x_hat
        ...
        ...
        "different operations which include the variable masked_x only"
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This doesn't quite work though, because x_hat is half the dimension of x: x is a matrix with (N,4) and x_hat is (N/2,4). But does the masking operation makes the backpropagation work? What is the difference instead of indexing it, like in my example?

Comment: If x and x_hat have different dimensions, then you'll need to use appropriate indexing to apply the x_hat values to the appropriate locations in x.